# Check if a date lies between two dates from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables as follow:

subscriptions:

```
user_id
started_at
ended_at
```

The subscription table contains historical membership for all the users. Users who never had subscriptions will not be included in this table. A user with X historical subscriptions will have X records in the table. For a user's most recent subscription, the col ended_at will be null if the membership is currently active.

transactions:

```
transaction_id (PK)
user_id
started_at
amount
```

This table tracks, for each historical transaction, the initiation time as well as amount along with user_id.

How can we know if the corresponding user has active gold membership at the time of making the transaction?

The output should look like something like.

```
transaction_id
user_membership_active (bool)
```

How can we check if a date from table1 lies between two dates from another table? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag the engine you are actually using and not "extras" that you might think of using at a future date. In addition, post DDL of the tables involved and sample data to better illustrate your situation. And `bool` is not a valid TSQL datatype.

Comment: Will keep it in mind going forward. Thanks for the suggestions. !

Comment: No reason to wait...

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
SELECT transaction_id,
       CASE
         WHEN ended_at IS NULL THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'False'
       END user_membership_active
FROM   transactions t1
       INNER JOIN subscriptions t2
               ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
                  AND t1.started_at BETWEEN t2.started_at AND
                                            ISNULL(t2.ended_at, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want to display, I'm assuming you would still insert a record in transactions table, regardless of whether there exists an active membership or not.

If you want to do this check after transaction record is inserted -

```
Select t.transaction_id,
case when t.started_at >= s.started_at 
and t.started_at < NVL(s.ended_at, SYSDATE())
then 'Y'  -- using Y/N for your boolean output
else 'N'
end as user_membership_active
from transactions t 
inner join subscriptions s on t.user_id = s.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want a flag.  One method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
       (exists (select 1
                from subscriptions s
                where s.user_id = t.user_id and
                      s.started_at <= t.started_at and
                      (s.ended_at > t.started_at or s.ended_at is null
                      )
               )
       ) as user_membership_active
from transactions t;
```

For performance, you want an index on `subscriptions(user_id, started_at, ended_at)`.

Note:  If a person has multiple concurrent subscriptions, this does *not* multiply the number of rows in the result set.